# how to add two 1-d array and arrange it using for loop?

Tags: java

The user should input 10 integer values for list1 and 10 integer values for list2. Your program should add the contents of list1 and list2 then store the sum to list3. Your program should display horizontally the values of list1, list2, and list3. Use loops.

here is the output:

```
List1 : 1 3 2 5 7 8 5 6 9 4
List2 : 2 1 4 3 2 1 4 2 0 2
List3 : 3 4 6 8 9 9 9 8 9 6
```

here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
public class List {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int list1[] = new int[10];
        int list2[] = new int[10];
        int i, j, k, num = 0, num1 = 0, num2 = 0;
        String input = " ";
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(System. in ));
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list1[i] = 0;
        }
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            list2[j] = 0;
        }
        try {
            for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.print("Input value for list[" + i + "] = ");
                input = in .readLine();
                num = Integer.parseInt(input);
                list1[i] = num;
            }
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                System.out.print("Input value for list[" + j + "] = ");
                input = in .readLine();
                num1 = Integer.parseInt(input);
                list2[j] = num1;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {}
        System.out.print("list1: ");
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print(list1[i] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("list2: ");
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            System.out.print(list2[j] + "\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        int list3[] = new int[10];
        list3[0] = list1[0] + list2[0];
        list3[1] = list1[1] + list2[1];
        list3[2] = list1[2] + list2[2];
        list3[3] = list1[3] + list2[3];
        list3[4] = list1[4] + list2[4];
        list3[5] = list1[5] + list2[5];
        list3[6] = list1[6] + list2[6];
        list3[7] = list1[7] + list2[7];
        list3[8] = list1[8] + list2[8];
        list3[9] = list1[9] + list2[9];
        System.out.print("list3: ");
        for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            System.out.print(list3[k] + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

my program is working correctly but i need to put the third list in loop can you help me?

Comment: Did you write this code on your own? If so, You have used 7 `for` loops, so you should be able to implement the 8th...

Comment: yes sir.. i dont know how to put  the list 3 in loop that is why i write it all. can i make a shortcut using for loop?  in order to make it more efficient can you help me?

Comment: Like `list3[k] = list1[k] + list2[k]`?

Comment: yeah i already put that but it is out of boundary exception

Comment: Don't fix the code in the question - it makes the question and answers nonsensical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In place of using sequential addition like in your code...

```
list3[0] = list1[0] + list2[0];
list3[1] = list1[1] + list2[1];
list3[2] = list1[2] + list2[2];
list3[3] = list1[3] + list2[3];
list3[4] = list1[4] + list2[4];
list3[5] = list1[5] + list2[5];
list3[6] = list1[6] + list2[6];
list3[7] = list1[7] + list2[7];
list3[8] = list1[8] + list2[8];
list3[9] = list1[9] + list2[9];
```

use this `for()` loop

```
for (int l = 0; l < list3.length; l++) {
    list3[l] = list1[l] + list2[l]; 
}
```

Comment: sir i didn't declare l there but it still working..  how did you do that?

Comment: because the variable l is declared in the for loop itself as int l = 0;

Comment: so can i remove this three sir? int i, j, k,

Comment: No you can't remove int i,j because they are required for other for loops... but you can remove k... as in my answer its not needed....

Comment: sir how to display the highest and the lowest vaule of list 3?

Comment: http://www.java-examples.com/find-largest-and-smallest-number-array-example ... go to this... just read the for loop part

Answer (score 0):

Your first two for loops that take in values are fine, now what you will need is a for loop that does something like this:

```
for(int i = 0, int length = list1.lengthl; i < length; i++)
{
   //add the stuff indexes by doing list1[i]+list2[i]
   //make sure to assign it to a new array
}
```

Edit: If wondering why I use a variable to store the length, it is because a regular loop is usually O(n) [big-oh] this means the time it takes to finish is directly proportional to how large the loop is (aka, 100 iterations will take more than 10, it has a slope of one). However, if we were to do i